# echo out multiple css classes for one div

Tags: php, css, echo

I'm only getting one CSS class to load in a situation where I'm echoing PHP variables as classes.
The html looks fine and should work, the two types of code I thought would work are pretty much the same, one having an `&nbsp;` in it, the other having an actual 'space' after the the first class (box)and in between the following (')

Code #1

```
echo '<div class="box ' .$color. '"></div>';?>
```

Code #2

```
echo '<div class="box&nbsp;' .$color. '"></div>';?>
```

The 2nd one certainly doesn't work because it's treating the `&nbsp;` as HTML and smashing both classes together (as `box&nbsp;$color`).
The first one looks right in the HTML view source/inspect element, but the 2nd class ("color")
isn't being applied. The first class will always load, but the 2nd one gets ignored.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the resulting HTML? It looks like it should work

Comment: `Code #1` should work, perhaps the first class color declaration has a higher priority than the second one (or some css somewhere else).

Comment: This is the rendered HTML code:
`<div class=​"box orange">​</div>​`

Comment: the problem must be in your CSS, how does the style look like that you are applying to your class `.orange`? Maybe you override it somewhere later.

Comment: the css is simply `.orange {background-color:orange;}`
It's not even registering in browser when I inspect the element. The other class is though.

Comment: http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/

Comment: OMG Michael shut up please its not related to the quotes...

Comment: @user2118228 put your test online so we can see the whole page, its not related with your PHP code its a CSS issue, problem a simple one

Comment: @Vinicious - Thanks for your interest, but the testing site is on a password protected server.
-Michael, the php is echoing everything as html properly.
See the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code is perfect... it should work. You might want to debug to make sure the variable $color actually has a value assigned to it before using the variable.

Comment: yes, the class will change in the html on the page, as in it's rendered as `<div class=​"box orange">​</div>​` or `<div class=​"box blue">​</div>`​ etc. The css is not being applied though. And it is written correctly in the stylesheet, and there are no duplicates of the class name.

Comment: Have the two classes i.e.box and orange been defined in the same stylesheet? If not, do check in firebug->net to see if the stylesheet where .orange style is defined is actually being called by the browser.

Comment: I was starting my class name with a number. You cannot start a class number. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I tried it out myself with no issues. Here is the code I used. Hope that helps

PHP File:

```
<?php
    $color = 'red';
    echo '<div class="box ' .$color. '"></div>'; ?>
```

CSS File:

```
.red { width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: I think this situation would work, but my situation is this: The variable `$color` is being determined from a php include which runs a `foreach` script associating `$color` with the dynamic value from an array using an if statement resulting in repectful css class ($color="green", $color="orange", etc.
For some reason the css is not being applied, it displays the class but does not render it in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - my css classes began with a number.
For brevity's sake I altered my code so everyone could get an idea of the situation. Thanks to all. You cannot start a CSS class with a number.